# phone gap update query issue with syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

06-27 13:30:36.635: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6490): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "AIRCRAFT": syntax error, db=xxx

Hi i have been facing the above issue in android with phonegap storage api with below code

```
 function updateAircraft(tx, data) {
  try {
    var sql = "UPDATE AIRCRAFT SET AIRCRAFT_ID='"+data.aircraftId+"'       AIRCRAFT='"+data.tailNumber+"' OPERATOR_ID='"+data.operatorId+"' FLIGHT_SCHEDULE_ID='"+data.flightScheduleId+"' ETOPS_CERTIFIED_IND='"+data.etopsCertifiedInd+"' RVSM_CERTIFIED_IND='"+data.rvsmCertifiedInd+"' STOCK_NUM_CODE='"+data.stockNumberCode+"' WHERE AIRCRAFT_ID='" + data.aircraftId+"'";
    console.log(sql);
    //tx.executeSql(sql, [data.aircraftId, data.tailNumber, data.operatorId, data.flightScheduleId, data.etopsCertifiedInd, data.rvsmCertifiedInd, data.stockNumberCode],updateAircraftSuccessCB,updateAircraftErrorCB)
    tx.executeSql(sql, [],updateAircraftSuccessCB,updateAircraftErrorCB)
    console.log('updated record into aircrat' + data.aircraftId);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
```

}

can any one help me what syntax is wrong in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There [must be commas](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) between the fields to be updated:

```
sql = "UPDATE AIRCRAFT SET AIRCRAFT_ID='"+...+"',  AIRCRAFT='"+..."+"', ...";
```